# Show that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n^3$ is congruent to 0,1,-1 modulo 9.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Having a little difficulties with this one. Tried thinking of going down the line of even/odd proofs, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: $1^3=1, 2^3=-1, 3^3=0, 4^3 = 1, 5^3=-1, 6^3=0, 7^3 = 1, 8^3 = -1$.

Comment: Or note that $(a + 3 k)^{3} \equiv a^{3} \pmod{9}$, so you just need to check $0^{3}, 1^{3}, 2^{3}$.

Comment: Where $a$ and $k$ are any integer? Would $a=n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any integer has at least one of these representations: 
$$3k, 3k+1, 3k-1$$

in cubic power

$$27k^3, 27k^3 + 27k^2 + 9k + 1, 27k^3 - 27k^2 + 9k -1$$

all of them are either dividable by 9 or remaining = -1/+1.

Comment: How exactly did you jump from the question to the $3k, 3k+1, 3k-1$. I understand it, I'm just missing something in the thought process I guess.

Comment: $3k-1, 3k, 3k+1$ were dictated by remainders -1, 0, 1, and of course $3k$ was dictated from 9.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo 9 table:

$x\equiv 0 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^2\equiv 0 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 0 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 1 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 1 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 1 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 2 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 4 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 8 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 3 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 0 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 0 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 4 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 7 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 1 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 5 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 7 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 8 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 6 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 0 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 0 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 7 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 4 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 1 \bmod9$

$x\equiv 8 \bmod 9\rightarrow x^2\equiv 1 \bmod 9 \rightarrow x^3\equiv 8 \bmod9$

alternatively:

$(3k)^3=27k^3$

$(3k+1)^3=27k^3+3*(9k^2)+3(3k)+1=9(3k^3+3k^2+k)+1,$

$(3k+2)^3=3k^3+3(2*9k^2)+3(4*3k)+8=9(3k^3+6k^2+4k)+8$

The modulo table allways works for proving these things, but the other one is nicer. since $8\equiv -1 \bmod9$ you do get what you want.